# Parsing Micro Focus XML in COBOL variables

Tags: xml-parsing, cobol, microfocus

I have the following xml-structure that I want to parse in Cobol.

```
<LDO>
  <OD>1</OD>     //OD 1'st occurrence
  <OLD>1</OLD>    //OLD 1'st occurrence
  <OLD>2</OLD>    //OLD 2'nd occurrence
  <OLD>3</OLD>    //OLD 3'rd occurrence
  <OD>2</OD>     //OD 2'nd occurrence
  <OLD>4</OLD>    //OLD 4'th occurrence
</LDO>
```

As you guys can see there is several OLD tags after an OD tag. What I want to do is reading this xml file step by step and display it's attributes in the following way:

1
1
2
3
2
4

```
           READ xml-stream.
       START xml-stream KEY IS OD.

       *>check status

       START xml-stream KEY IS OLD.
       *> check stream status                 

       PERFORM UNTIL EXIT
            READ xml-stream next key is
            old
            IF  stream-status = -7
               EXIT PERFORM
            END-IF
            *> check stream status less than 0
            display od-value
            display old-value
```

But the od-value doesn't change when i excecute the program. It return the following values

**1**
1
2
3
**1**
4

I want that the second occurrence to return the value of the second element OD not the first one.

I would like some help to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "[xml parse](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.studee60ux%2FHRLHLHPDFC0F.html)" syntax:

```
   program-id. xp.
   01 xdoc pic x(1024) value
   " <LDO>" &
    "  <OD>1</OD>" &
    "  <OLD>1</OLD>" &
    "  <OLD>2</OLD>" &
    "  <OLD>3</OLD>" &
    "  <OD>2</OD>" &
    "  <OLD>4</OLD>" &
    "</LDO>".

   procedure division.
        Xml parse xdoc processing procedure p
            ON EXCEPTION
              display 'XML document error 'XML-CODE
          NOT ON EXCEPTION
              display 'XML document successfully parsed'
          END-XML
        goback.

         p.
            Evaluate xml-event
                When 'START-OF-ELEMENT'
                When 'CONTENT-CHARACTERS'
                  exhibit named xml-text
                When 'CONTENT-CHARACTER'
                  exhibit named xml-text
                When 'END-OF-ELEMENT'
                  exhibit named xml-event
                When other
                  exhibit named xml-event
        End-evaluate
        .


   end program xp.
```